# Javascript: Precision strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Suppose,

```
var x = .6 - .5;

var y = 10.2 – 10.1;

var z = .2  -  .1;
```

Comparison result

```
x == y;     // false

x == .1;    // false

y == .1;    // false
```

but

```
z == .1;    // true
```

Why Javascript show such behavior?

Comment: Your first two comparisons are a bit strange. Why would you expect them to match? (-0.1 vs 0.1)

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because floating point is not perfectly precise. You can end up with *slight* differences.

*(Side note: I think you meant `var x = .6 - .5;` Otherwise, you're comparing `-0.1` with `0.1`.)*

JavaScript uses [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) double-precision 64-bit floating point ([ref](http://es5.github.com/#x8.5)). This is an *extremely good* approximation of floating point numbers, but there is no perfect way to represent all floating point numbers in binary.

Some discrepancies are easier to see than others. For instance:

```
console.log(0.1 + 0.2); // "0.30000000000000004"
```

There are some JavaScript libraries out there that do the "decimal" thing a'la C#'s `decimal` type or Java's `BigDecimal`. That's where the number is actually stored as a series of decimal digits. But they're not a panacea, they just have a different class of problems (try to represent `1 / 3` accurately with it, for instance). "Decimal" types/libraries are fantastic for financial applications, because we're used to dealing with the style of rounding required in financial stuff, but there is the cost that they tend to be slower than IEEE floating point.

Let's output your `x` and `y` values:

```
var x = .6 - .5;
console.log(x); // "0.09999999999999998"

var y = 10.2 - 10.1;
console.log(y); // "0.09999999999999964"
```

No great surprise that `0.09999999999999998` is `!=` to `0.09999999999999964`. :-)

You can rationalize those a bit to make the comparison work:

```
function roundTwoPlaces(num) {
  return Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
}

var x = roundTwoPlaces(0.6 - 0.5);

var y = roundTwoPlaces(10.2 - 10.1);

console.log(x);       // "0.1"
console.log(y);       // "0.1"
console.log(x === y); // "true"
```

Or a more generalized solution:

```
function round(num, places) {
    var mult = Math.pow(10, places);
    return Math.round(num * mult) / mult;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/avohiq) | [source](http://jsbin.com/avohiq/edit)

Note that it's still possible for accuracy crud to be in the resulting number, but at least two numbers that are very, very, very close to each other, if run through `round` with the same number of places, should end up being the same number (even if that number isn't perfectly accurate).

Comment: Don't ever count on JavaScript's float number precision... =))

Comment: @benqus: Enh, it's good enough for most purposes. And remember it's not just JavaScript; a lot of systems use IEEE-754, which is freaky smart bit fiddling.

Comment: That last trick you do there is interesting mate! I mean that's crazy no matter what standard JS uses. =) I'm gonna save this solution if you don't mind. Does this work with smaller numbers, like: 0.00245?

Comment: @benqus: Yes, I've added a more generalized solution. There's no guarantee, of course, that dividing by 100 (or whatever) won't result in a similarly-awkward bit of crud in the result. But at least if you feed two numbers in that are very, very close to one another, they should (in theory) both come out with the same value (even if that value isn't perfectly accurate).